# Rails 3 - Friendly params in url (GET)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I have a rails 3 app and now i implementing filter for my catalog. Filters form pass data to controller through GET request. As a result i have link like this in my browser after i submit 
my form (apply search):

```
http://localhost:3001/shoes?filter%5BShoeBottomType%5D%5B%5D=2&filter%5BShoeClassification%5D%5B%5D=1&filter%5BShoeClassification%5D%5B%5D=2&filter%5BShoeElation%5D%5B%5D=3&filter%5BShoeElation%5D%5B%5D=4&filter%5BShoeElation%5D%5B%5D=5&filter%5BShoeLiningColor%5D%5B%5D=2&filter%5BShoeLiningColor%5D%5B%5D=3&filter%5BShoeLiningColor%5D%5B%5D=4&filter%5BShoeTopColor%5D%5B%5D=1&filter%5BShoeTopColor%5D%5B%5D=2&filter%5Bonly_action%5D%5B%5D=1&page=2
```

Is there a way to do URL more beautiful?

PS i dont want use POST request, because I read that it is bad for SEO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLDR: just leave it.

HTML forms serialize in a straightforward manner; the parameters are named after the HTML elements. The actual issue here is how the form elements are named. It looks like they have names like `filter[ShoeBottomType][]`; look into your HTML to see the `name` attributes. Since you're in Rails, I'm guessing you having a filter hash passed to your Rails controller method as a single argument, and since Rails expects hashes to use a certain URL [format](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters) for hashes and arrays (it has to know how to deserialize it from the request), the form helper writes the form that way. And yours is especially complicated because the hash values are arrays, hence the extra set of brackets. Then it's URL encoded and you end up with an ugly mess.

You could avoid some of this problem by passing the inputs individually back to the controller instead of as a big hash. Something like:

```
def index
  shoe_bottom_types = params[:bottom_types]
  shoe_classifications = params[:classifications]
  shoe_elations = params[:elations]
  ...
```

which will get you to: `/shoes?bottomTypes[]=1&bottomTypes[]=2...`. That doesn't seem much better, and now your controller is all gross. And I don't see how you're going to get rid of the brackets entirely if you want to have more than one of the same filter. I guess you could get crazy and do your own parsing in your controller, like breaking apart `shoeBottomTypes=1|2`, but then you'll have to do your own form serialization too. Again, just not worth it.

Backing up for a sec, the SEO stuff doesn't make much sense. Search engines won't fill out your form; they just follow links. The real reason you should use GET is that (presumably), submitting your form doesn't have side effects, since it's just a search. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods); it's important to use the right HTTP methods. If you use POST, you'll get weird warnings on reloads and you won't be able to bookmark the search.

Backing up even further, why do you care, especially now that SEO is out of the picture? Just as a quick demo, I did a google search for the word "thing" and this was the URL:

https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=thing&pbx=1&oq=thing&aq=f&aqi=g2g-s1g1&aql=1&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=764l1877l0l1980l6l6l0l0l0l0l89l432l5l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=220ef4545fdef788&biw=1920&bih=1086

So URLs for form submissions can be long. The user won't even look at it.

The only possibility I can think of for why you'd care about the length/ugliness of your URL here is that you want, separately from the form, to create links to certain searches. There are several ways to handle that, but since I don't know whether that's relevant to you, I'll let that be a follow-up.

So bottom line, it looks like I'd expect, and trying to fix it sounds ugly and pointless.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use a POST request, then there is no other way then to put the form values in the URL -- they have to get to the server one way or another.

On the other hand however, I do not see why doing a POST would be bad for SEO and I would love to see the article that stated so.

Comment: For example - visitor get to the site, select some filters, look at result and then want share (get the link) to his/him/her friend. In my variant with looooong link, when friend open this link - it see the same result. If it will work via POST - the link was like http://localhost:3001/shoes and friend see all results without filtering. I hope that i explained clearly.

Comment: Instead of putting the filters in the URL, you could, for instance, save the form (or the results) to the database and return a ID as some sort of permalink mechanism ('`http://localhost/shoes?filter=25`'). Either way, I don't see how this would have any impact on SEO. I would still love to see the article that said so.

Comment: I use will_paginate gem (and will_paginate draw links that i show as example). So... try to use will_paginate + ajax.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you could add some custom routes to beautify your urls.

For example : 
    http://localhost:3001/shoes/Type/2/Classification/1,2/Elation/3,4,5/LiningColor/2,3,4/TopColor/1,2/only_action/1/page/2

This is far much shorter than your initial URL ;)

The counterpart is that, as far as I know, you have to use always the same order for params in your url.

The routing rule is the following :

```
match "shoes/Type/:type/Classification/:classification/Elation/:elation/LiningColor/:liningcolor/TopColor/:topcolor/only_action/:only_action/page/:page" => "shoes#show"
```

You can retrieve the passed values in `params` array. You have to split the string containing `,` in order to retrieve the multiple values.

Comment: If you're going the custom serialization/string-splitting route, I'd stick to using URL parameters: `shoes?type=2&classification=1,2&elation=3,4,5`. That would save you the custom route and the wacky ordering constraints. Also, presumably the filters are optional?